# Middle mouse button emulated even though disabled in xinput/libinput

Tags: mouse, xinput, libinput

It *should* be disabled, and yet I get middle mouse button clicks. When I run xinput list I get this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt Microsoft USB Optical Mouse        id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SQT USB Gaming Keyboard                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

... and a few more non-pointing devices. Examining each of these in turn, I see that only 9 (the mouse) has middle click emulation set... to zero.

```
Device 'PixArt Microsoft USB Optical Mouse':
    Device Enabled (152):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (154): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (288):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (289):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (290):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (291):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (292):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (293): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (294): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (295):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (296):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (297): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (298): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (299):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (300):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (301):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (302): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (303): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (273): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (274):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (275):    0, 0
    Device Node (276):  "/dev/input/event3"
    Device Product ID (277):    1118, 203
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (304):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (305):   1
```

And yet I get middle clicks in games. To prove I'm not going crazy, I wrote a tiny SDL2 program myself to check:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int quit = 0;
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Middle click detector",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0);

    while (!quit)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            quit = 1;
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_MIDDLE)
                printf("Middle clicked!\n");
            else if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                printf("Left clicked!\n");
            else if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT)
                printf("Right clicked!\n");
            else
                printf("What clicked?\n");
        }
    }
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

(compiled with gcc sdltest.c -Wall `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`)

Sure enough, if I hold left and click right, I get:

```
Left clicked!
Right clicked!
Middle clicked!
```

People who know anything about the input pipeline on Linux, can you please give me a clue where to look next? I'm at a loss. I'll also be grateful for anyone who can run the test program and confirm or deny that they have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It just occurred to me to test out with another mouse. No middle click.

This seems to be a physical (mis)feature of the PixArt Microsoft USB Optical Mouse.